# Check for UUID version in swift

Tags: swift, uuid

Is there a way to check for UUID version? 
I know the `UUID().uuidString` is version 4. 
and I have a variable that comes from the server and it is in UUID version 1.

now I want to check for the version of UUID and decide for my actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 4 UUIDs have the form `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` where x is any hexadecimal digit and y is one of 8, 9, A, or B as described here:
 [How to determine if a string is a valid v4 UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19989922/2907715)

If you are using only version 4 and version 1 then you can do the following:

```
func checkUUIDVersion(uuid: String) -> Int {
    let regx = "^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}"
    if uuid.uppercased().range(of: regx, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil {
        return 4;
    }
    return 1;
}
```